# Git: a tool to manage and to structure Projects?

Tags: git, maven, version-control

I want to learn project design and structuring Git -repositories. There are tools such as Maven for Java projects [here](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) but cannot find anything for Git. Maven threads look poor-quality, except this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829/structure-of-projects-in-version-control) -- warning poor-quality threads: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621099/integrating-maven-non-maven-projects), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893469/could-free-pascal-benefit-of-something-like-apache-maven), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015036/maven-support-for-android-projects), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881157/using-maven-for-r-projects) -- Y (more). So I surely want to use something else to it!

**Helper questions**

> 1. How projects should be designed?
> 2. Something like Maven for Non-Java -projects?
> 3. Do I need something like Maven really to design a project?
> 4. Does there exist tools to manage non-Java projects with Git?

Comment: Git and Maven do totally different things. Git is a version control system. As you said it keeps track of changes to your code and conserves versions of it. Maven on the other hand is a tool for building. You can define goals to be executed when building your application and it helps you manage dependencies to apis and other projects. I suggest reading: http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html

Comment: @Dan Maven is only for Java -based projects according to the tutorial. Does there exist something similar for other languages? I find it still hard to see why I would use something like that. Using Java for building a turbine sounds scary X|

Comment: Which language in particular? I don't see why you think building software for a turbine with Java is scary.

Comment: @Dan Is there some difference? Some language-agnostic solution? I like to use Python, R and certain functional languages but I hope agnostic solutions.

Comment: I haven't heard of one. Hard to imagine one since different languages might have different solutions for handling dependencies. There seem to be alternatives for other languages though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392781/is-there-an-alternative-to-maven-for-net-windows-forms-projects

Comment: Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324108/maven-equivalent-for-python. Couldn't find one for R though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet but perhaps soon! You may be able to solve the problem by combining proper workflow tools with some social tools if you need to collaborate. Choose Workflow -tools if you are doing thing alone.

**Workflow -tools**

> - Git's submodules
> - Gitslave minimizes the amount of repetitive commands, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12027861/164148).
> - Git-subtree may help you replace some submodules, more [here](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/subtree).

**Social -tools**

> - Gitolite. Now there are two different kinds of permissions: the basic *ix permissions and the Gitolite -permissions defined by the
>     manager such as perms to commit and perms to clone a repo.
> - Gerrit -code-review -project [here](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) that blurs the line between a
>     manager and a dev, screenshots
>     [here](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.4.2/intro-quick.html#_manually_verifying_the_change).
>     It looks to have some features similar to Bitbucket.org and Github.com
>     such as verifying a commit -- although Bitbucket uses "a thumb" for
>     this, intrinsically the same.

**Perhaps related**

> 1. [Git: how to avoid repetitive committing with sub-sub-sub... Git -repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068119/avoid-repetitive-committing-with-sub-sub-sub-git-repos)
> 2. [Changing permissions with deep Git repository-repository -tree with sub-repos and submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790634/changing-permissions-with-deep-git-repository-repository-tree-with-sub-repos-an)
> 3. [How can I host Git repositories and manage my content-hosting myself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007679/how-can-i-host-git-repositories-and-manage-my-content-hosting-myself)